# Where online do Danish roleplaying conversations happen?

Tags: online-resources

Denmark is a reasonably small country with what I understand to be a quite lively rpg scene. Finland has about as much population and our online discussions are focused on a small number of websites, so something similar might very well be true of Denmark.

I am interested in the major forums, G+ groups, Facebook groups, Discord servers, IRC channels, and whatever similar media people are using nowadays. I am only interested in major ones; defined as follows: Most Danes who discuss roleplaying games online are aware of them and know that many people use them.

What are the most significant online Danish roleplaying communities, and what is their significance in the Danish rpg scene?